# mongoose where to put model functions that can be exposed globally

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am using `utils.js` right now which can be required anywhere in my API controllers.

I'm wondering if this is a good way of doing it.

I might call methods whenever I have a Job object like:

```
var require('../utils');

//express route callback
job = utils.job.getCreatorProfile(job);
res.send(job);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would typically want to create a method like `getCreatorProfile` as a [static method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) of your model by defining it on your schema:

```
jobSchema.statics.getCreatorProfile = function(job) { ... };
```

Which makes it available everywhere as a method on the model class:

```
job = Job.getCreatorProfile(job);
```